# Average pressure on a 3D box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure

I have a particle inside a box of dimensions $L_{x},L_{y},L_{z}$

the energies are given by $E=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\pi^2\sum_{i}\frac{n_{i}^2}{L_{i}^2}$

I calculated the force by $-\frac{\partial E}{\partial L_{i}}$ exerted by the particle on the i-th face of the box. I am now trying to get the average pressure exerted in terms of the average energy and the volume $L_{x}L_{y}L_{z}$. I know that $P_{i}=\frac{F_{i}}{A_{i}}$ with $A_{x}=L_{y}L_{z}$ and so on.

First doubt: Do i have to count twice $P_{i}$ as there are two faces for every axes that will feel presure?

Second doubt: If I count twice each one, I am getting $P=\frac{4E}{V}$ where V is the volume. If I count x y and z only once I get a 2 instead of a 4. However, I was expecting to get $E=PV$, like the energy of a gas, it is bothering me to get that 2, or 4... makes me doubt

Comment: For an ideal gas with three quadratic degrees of freedom, $E = 3/2 PV$

Comment: Thanks, it means I shouldn't count twice each axis... do you know why? (I can get the 3 by making it square so thats fine)

and where did you find that? i didnt find that result

thanks!

Comment: It is quite easy to prove for classical gas (can be found on any textbook on kinetic theory of gases). For quantum gases (bosons and fermions) the math is a bit more complicated, but the result remains same (can be found in any textbook of statistical mechanics e.g. the one by Reif). For calculation of pressure for classical non relativistic gas, you have to consider the momentum transferred to a $\textbf{single wall}$(so no double counting) per unit time. For quantum gas, you have to write the partition function and proceed using standard methods of statistical mechanics.

Comment: For the derivation for classical gas, head over to the equilibrium properties section. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases

Comment: Thank you Archisiman, I get it now, except for the single wall part... I mean, there are two walls in the x direction, and each of them could feel pressure, I guess we are supposing one of them remains fixed (at 0) and the other one is the one whose position is changing, right? so if the first wall would move 1 cm and the other one 0.5 cm, we are considering the first one to remain still while the second one moves 1.5 cm?

Comment: If the walls move at a constant speed, or if you do the analysis after the walls have moved and stopped, you can fix the 0 of your scale in either of the walls and can say that the other one has moved 1.5 cm. Pressure is defined as perpendicular force per unit area on a surface, so you should consider one wall at a time.